# Clarification on Multiplication in $GF(2^3)$ vs. Boolean Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, boolean-algebra, cryptography, binary-operations

While experimenting with finite fields, specifically $GF(2^3)$, I stumbled upon a puzzling situation when comparing multiplication operations to those in Boolean algebra.

Let's take two elements $A$ and $B$ from $GF(2^3)$, both represented by the binary number $011$. In Boolean algebra, multiplying $A$ and $B$ would look like this:

$$A \cdot B = 011 \cdot 011 = 1001_2 = 9_{10}$$

This is straightforward binary multiplication with a carry. However, multiplication in $GF(2^3)$ follows different rules, where we don't account for carry-over and instead reduce by an irreducible polynomial. For instance:

$$A \cdot B = (x + 1) \cdot (x + 1) = x^2 + x + x + 1 = x^2 + 1$$

In binary form, this polynomial $x^2 + 1$ corresponds to $101_2$, which is $5_{10}$, which is entirely unrelated to $1001_2$ from the binary arithmetic. It seems to me that $GF(2^3)$ doesn't really "do multiplication" in the way I'm familiar with from Boolean algebra and binary arithmetic.

Here's where I'm seeking clarification: why does multiplication in $GF(2^3)$ ignore the carry-over?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Taking multiplication modulo 8 isn't the same as the finite field $GF(2^3)$: in fact, mod 8 isn't even a field. So one can't expect the particular function between the two you've chosen to preserve multiplication.

Comment: @Chessnator
Thanks for the note. Now, I can see where is my mistake regarding ing the modulo. I understand that we take mod 2 of the coefficients as here:
$$A \cdot B = a_2 b_2 \ mod \ 2 \ x^2 +  a_1 b_1 \ mod \ 2 \ x + a_0 b_0 \ mod \ 2$$
But still, this multiplication operation doesn't make sense. It should be called rather XOR not multiplication.

Comment: There are two irreducible cubic polynomials in $GF(2)[x]$, and the operation you've defined in general depends on which one you've used to construct $GF(8)$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Could you please elaborate on what it means to construct $GF(8)$? And how the irreducible polynomials can converge the results with the ordinary binary arithmetic?

Comment: Like you say, we can think of multiplication in $GF(8)$ as multiplying in $GF(2)[x]$ and then keeping only the remainder modulo some irreducible polynomial $p(x) \in GF(2)[x]$ of degree $3$, hence identifying $GF(8) \leftrightarrow GF(2)[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$. There are $2$ choices for $p$, and they will give different (but isomorphic) multiplication operations.

Comment: As a $GF(2)$-vector space $GF(8)$ is just $GF(2) \oplus GF(2) \oplus GF(2)$, hence addition in $GF(8)$ is just bitwise $\mathtt{XOR}$. I don't know a nice interpretation of multiplication in $GF(8)$ in terms of Boolean operations. You might try considering the analogous problem for $GF(4) \cong GF(2)[x] / \langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ first.

Comment: Thanks, @TravisWillse. I'm just trying to understand your explanation. I know from the finite fields definition that $GF(p^m)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p \bigoplus \mathbf{Z}_p \bigoplus ... \bigoplus \mathbf{Z}_p$ $m$ times so I understand that its a bitwise $\texttt{XOR}$ operation for the addition, but still in Boolean it yields another result:
Addition in $GF(8)$: $$A + B = (x+1) + (x+1) = 0$$
Addition in Boolean: $$A + B = 110_2 = 6_{10}$$

Comment: @Travis Willse You should transform your comments into an answer that I would be happy to upvote.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for your input. My aim was to draw parallels between Boolean algebra, fundamental in digital circuits, and field theory in abstract algebra, as both involve binary operations. Understanding the conceptual transition from the former, which is ubiquitous in electrical engineering, to the latter, crucial in cryptography, can be nontrivial. Hence, I sought clarity on their distinct rule sets.

Comment: @JeanMarie I will also be happy to upvote them if turned to comments.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Building on our discussion, could you clarify what structure in abstract algebra Boolean algebra most resembles? My confusion arises when comparing it to finite fields in digital logic applications, given their shared binary nature yet distinct algebraic properties.

Comment: I would probably not call that example "addition in Boolean"---so-called Boolean rings have the property that every element satisfies $r + r = 0$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring)---but rather addition of integers expressed in base $2$ (possibly modulo $8$).

Comment: Put another way, addition in $GF(8)$ is Boolean in the sense that $r + r = 0$ for all elements, but addition of integers (perhaps modulo 8) is not.

Comment: Why do you call those operations *Boolean algebra*. There is [a natural Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)) with elements consisting of strings of three bits. The operations are *meet* and *join*, the former means bitwise AND, and the latter bitwise OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition and multiplication operations in $\Bbb Z / \langle 8 \rangle$, that is on the integers modulo $8$, are simply entirely different from the addition and multiplication operations on the field $GF(8)$. To wit, modulo $8$ the number $2_{10} = 010_2$ has no inverse under multiplication, whereas every nonzero element of $GF(8)$ has a multiplicative inverse.

I would, by the way, describe addition in $GF(8)$ as *Boolean* but would *not* describe addition modulo $8$ that way: In a [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) all elements $r$ satisfy $r + r = 0$, whereas most integers modulo $8$ do not.

**Remark** As a vector space over $GF(2)$, $GF(8) \cong GF(2) \oplus GF(2) \oplus GF(2)$, so we can identify addition on $GF(8)$ with Boolean addition on that direct sum, or equivalently bitwise $\mathtt{XOR}$ on the set of binary strings of length $3$.

Comment: [+1] Very good "separating lines" between different structures.